# I cannot change the inputType, hint anything for my EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I'm trying to simple application.
I dragged and dropped PlainText and I cannot change the inputType, hint, text.
I'm new to Android Studio.
My screen looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TAuT.png).

Comment: Go to view all attributes and check.

Comment: you are to new for android development,watch some video tutorial on youtube it will help you

Comment: I advice you to write your layout using text editor (you can see this option on the bottom next to design card). And if you still want to do it in design card try to click show all attributes where you should be able to find inputType.

Comment: Agreed with @Ikazuchi. And before posting such questions, search on google.

Comment: If you all 3 above take a look at the image the OP posted you would see that his problem is that the design editor is problematic. There are no attributes there to set. This is his question.

Comment: @mTak he will get options once he clicks on show all attributes option.

Comment: @manishpoddar in the image is shown that he clicked on the edittext and on the right there are no atributes. hint is both in all and less attributes so he would see it

Answer (score 0):

```
You will get this result after drag and drop:
            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name" />
```

What you need is to do :
 1. If you want hint to show remove line " android:text="Name""

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="hint text goes here" />
```

Comment: I got that also when i clicked Text.